# Show hidden text during find

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table of data with several columns. One of them is a comment column with varying length of text. Some comment is very short but some of them can be quite long. Now I only display the first 50 characters of the comment and I put the original text into the "title" attribute so that users still able to read the whole value.

By truncating the string the table looks okay but now users are not able find (CTRL+F in browsers) anything in the rest of the text that was truncated.

So my idea is to make the whole comment hidden in the source code but visible to the browser's find mechanism. Is it possible somehow? What do you guys suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to try to find a different approach. Often when you encounter problems like this, it means you need to try something else.

Answer (score 1):

Simple/funny solution:

Set the comment container CSS to `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow:scroll;`, and set  width and height for the container if necessary. Should show only a portion of text for the users, but can be fully-readable by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thinking about it...What does the browser do when you use the find feature? It scrolls to the text it found and selects it. How is that possible if the text is not visible? I can think of no way that that could work. The only option I can think of is to implement your own find feature, overriding the browser's. It would look through posted comments and find the text just like the browser would, except it would be capable of looking through the hidden text *and* possibly expanding it. As to how exactly to override the browser's find, perhaps you could bind to Ctrl+F, and in that binding, `return false` to prevent the browser using its find. I don't know if that would work, it's just an idea. As you said, the base problem is that the browser can't search through hidden text, and I know of no way to make it do so.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine its possible without dirrty tricks, like font-size:0.1px or such.
You could provide your users the option to display the full-size text or implement your own search feature for this. why should a user expect results using the native search engine on data that is not present for him.
you could bind to CTRL-F but maybe somebody changed keybinds or is using the menu, so thats a dead end for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good answer, but well: There is a bug in Webkit and maybe other engines. If you set the text to `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden;`, it will get visually truncated but will appear again if a search-match was found in the hidden text.

I used a similar technique since six years to hide text from buttons, that are styled with an background image:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: 120%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```